# Python webscraper click xbrl link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to go to the edgar database of the SEC and click the first new 8-K filing available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import chromedriver_binary
import time


#locate Chrome Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Python38\chromedriver.exe')
#Go to the url
driver.get("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=8-K&owner=include&count=40&action=getcurrent")
print(driver.title)


#select first element available
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a[1]")
#click element from line 22
elem.click()
```

giving the following result:

[image]

This is where I get stuck. I am trying to get the little script to click the current report. Using the chrome dev tools I located the element to the following:

[image]

Now I have tried to locate the Xpath which gives me: //tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]//a

```
XBelem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]//a")
XBelem.click()
```

However if I try to use it like I did in the previous file it doesn't do anything.

if I add a "." in front of the //tr.. it just returns me to the homepage.

Comment: After clicking und navigating to the new url, did you update your current url? Because it might be that your driver is still stucked in the old html-file of the previous site. url = driver.current_url () --> driver.get(url). Also the xpath I get from the second link is: //*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a

Comment: I have tried that xpath a few days ago but it gave me "Invalid Syntax (Pyflakes E) so I thought it was completly wrong. Edit url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url) seems to have solved it. could you write it as an answer so I can accept it? thank you very much!

Comment: You can shorten your XPath with `(//table[2]//a)[2]` for the first link and `(//table//a)[1]` for the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case, that you didn't upgrade your current url, so the driver is still stucked in the HTML-File of the old url. You can update it by:

```
url = driver.current_url()
driver.get(url)
```